# Colourize specific files in git status result

Tags: git, github

To not accidentally push my configuration files I want to colorize specific files in `git status` result. I tried this command

```
 git config --global color.status.yellow "**/config/database.yml **/config/email.yml **/frontend/package-lock.json **/frontend/config/development.js"
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I tried restarting the iTerm as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you can do with [git config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-colorstatusltslotgt) options:

> `color.status.<slot>`
>
> Use customized color for status colorization. `<slot>` is one of `header` (the header text of the status message), `added` or `updated` (files which are added but not committed), `changed` (files which are changed but not added in the index), `untracked` (files which are not tracked by Git), `branch` (the current branch), `nobranch` (the color the no branch warning is shown in, defaulting to red), `localBranch` or `remoteBranch` (the local and remote branch names, respectively, when branch and tracking information is displayed in the status short-format), or `unmerged` (files which have unmerged changes).

As you can see, it does not support specifying specific files.